# Error: The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Tags: php, mysql, installation, wamp, wampserver

I am learning PHP+MySQL. I did not buy a web hosting plan, so for now I plan to test everything locally. From my research, I found WAMPserver.com. I downloaded the install for WAMP and did a basic setup without really changing anything in the setup or doing any actions afterwards. I wanted to create some databases and practice in SQL, but when I click phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

```
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

I tried googling for this and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I tried changing the setup files in c:/wamp/apps but I dont think I did it correct because it still didn't work (i tried changing the phpmyadmin and sqlbuddy config files to 127.0.0.1 on localhost, didnt work so I changed it back to localhost).

**EDIT:** So as of now my config file in the apps phpmyadmin folder is not changed from the way it came on the install. So under port, socket, password it has nothing. Do I need to configure this maybe to solve the problem? If so, what should I use?

Similarly, I have not changed the config file for sqlbuddy1.3.2 in the apps folder

Comment: Try checking the mysql log (right click the wamp icon > mysql > log)

Comment: Check the color of wamp in tray bar. white = all the server run properly, yellow = not all servers running or problem with one server, red = wamp server are off

Comment: Marc, everything is green.

Bassneck, what am I looking for in the log?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall wamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Is WAMP actually started and running? It's basically (to me at least) a program that you have to start up to get anything working. You have to run wamp/wampmanager.exe (on Windows).

If you're using Windows there should be a WAMP icon in your task tray if it is started and running.

Comment: If he gets this error, this means, at least apache and php are running

Comment: yep, in the bottom right corner in my task tray the WAMP button is green.

Answer (score 0):

Have you a apache or mysql server (or any other server) already installed and running on your computer before you installed wamp ?
Even some softwares may use port 80 (HTTP) or 3306 (MySQL).

I am not sure, but it can be a port already occupied.

Try this in a command line (as administrator if needed), it will tell you the software listening to a port in your computer.

```
netstat
```

or

```
netstat -a -b
```

Comment: ok I ran it both commands and got a bunch of data. When I run netstat (not including the -a -b), do I look under local address or foreign address for the ports that are being listened to? Under local address, there is myname-randomnumberscharacters:http then foreign address localhost: 1159.

Comment: goto localhost:80 and see if you see anything

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some old my.ini or my.cnf file lying somewhere on your hd with options no longer supported by new mysql versions. Find my_print_defaults.exe and run it to see where mysql is looking for its configuration files and in what order. Rename any old files to something else and leave only the one in the wamp directory.

Comment: I tried running my print defaults and it opened up, text scrolled really fast, then the command prompt screen just closed. I do not think it is an old version of MySQL as it was in the WAMP folder and I have never installed mysql locally before

Comment: you can run it from command prompt itself, also look for last error in the mysql log

Answer (score 0):

Try xampp. Super simple installation and works like a charm.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Move your files over and make sure you stop your WAMP server or Apache will collide.